# UIScrollView and PageControl: space between views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

Is it possible to add some black space between views that are shown  by a UIScrollView and PageControl. Each of these views is a simple view controller with an UiImageView in it, similar to the photo album. I want to add the space, so when the users are switching "pages"/photos, there is some gap in between.

```
    scrollArea.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollArea.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollArea.frame.size.width * [photos count], scrollArea.frame.size.height);
    scrollArea.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollArea.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollArea.scrollsToTop = NO;
    scrollArea.delegate = self;
```

I wouldn't want to make the images smaller, but that would do the trick. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have full control over placement of all UIViews inside of the UIScrollView and the placement of the page control in relation to the scrollview.   There is no automatic layout done, it's up to you to properly set the frame property of all the objects so that they fit "nicely" within the "page" of the scrollview (visible area = one "page")

Here's an example off adding content to multiple "pages" in a scrollview at a particular x,y within each page:

```
NSMutableArray *myLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numPages];
CGFloat itemX = 10;
CGFloat itemY = 20;
CGFloat itemWidth = 40;
CGFloat itemHeight = 50;

for ( int i = 0; i < numPages; ++i )
{
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( itemX, itemY, itemWidth, itemHeight )];
    [myScrollView addSubview:lbl];
    [myLabels addObject:lbl];
    [lbl release];
    itemX += myScrollView.frame.size.width;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but how can I do it? I tried to make the frame bigger than the phone screen, but didn't work.

Comment: With a scroll view you do not increase its frame size to add content, you increase the contentSize.   A UIScrollView will not scroll in a dimension (left/right up/down) if the contentSize in that dimension is not larger than the frame size of that dimension.   See my edits for some code for adding objects to multiple pages of a UIScrollView